# unordered set remove/insert in a loop

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

The values of a `std::unordered_set` are not mutable, as they are both key and value. What is the correct way to modify an element of a `std::unordered_set`, if its element are first removed, modified and then reinserted? The `erase` does not invalidate any iterators, but the `insert` may. The obvious answer is to use the iterator, that the `erase` returns. One way, one could deal with this, I guess, is to reset the loop iterator to the beginning of an `unordered_set`, after a successful insert. I'd like to make sure, it is the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `erase` does not invalidate any iterators, but the `insert` may.

You can always check beforehand if `insert` is going to do that:

> If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are
>   invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. References are not
>   invalidated. Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is
>   equal to or greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`.
>   (from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert))

So, if you watch out for rehashing, your approach could work. Of course it leaves you with the problem of what to do when you detect that rehashing *will* occur.

You can reduce the probability of rehashing by increasing the capacity of the set before the loop.

The simplest way of dealing with rehashing is to start over after rehashing. Maybe there are other ways to deal with it but I wouldn't risk it.

---

Having said all these, what you are describing here seems to indicate that you probably need another container. If the `unordered_set` is really the best container for your application, I would most likely still go with [Martin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970277/341970), namely with an intermediate container. It's less messy and I can see what's going on; I can reason about correctness.

Comment: Ah, I see, advance loop iterator by 1, save it, and then use it after insert. Still, one might re encounter the modified element later, one has to watch out for that.

Comment: @user1095108 Please post a minimal example. Show us what you have in mind. I don't think you would skip elements, but I definitely see the problem of encountering an already modified element.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are better off using an intermediate container, like this:

```
unordered_set<int> original;
...
vector<int> temporary;
for (auto it = original.begin(), itEnd = original.end(); it != itEnd; ) {
    if (...) {
        int newValue = ...;
        auto toDelete = it++;
        original.erase(toDelete);
        temporary.push_back(newValue);
    } else {
       ...
       ++it;
    }
}
original.insert(temporary.begin(), end.begin());
```

Comment: Sure, but `vector` usually allocates from the heap. This may not be cheap.

Comment: Of course it depends on the size of your data and the context your program runs in, but I wouldn't be surprised if storing and bulk-inserting the new values was more efficient than the additional logic needed to handle the new entries in the set. Also, bulk-inserting can be more efficient than inserting items one-by-one, depending on the `unordered_set` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary `unordered_set` that you will fill iterating on the first one (with an hint) then swap the original set with the temporary.

Comment: This sounds better than the `vector` solution.